# What does this sentence mean?

Tags: expressions

A lapidary style is polished and cut to the point of transparency.

(It is about Hemingway's writing style)

Answer (score 3):

I found some more context.

> The result was a style that has been described as realistic, hard-boiled, spare, minimalist and lapidary.  A lapidary style is polished and cut to the point of transparency.  It doesn't seem to be doing much.  It does not demand that attention is paid to it.

I have done lapidary before.  With lapidary, you start with ordinary looking rocks that you find on the ground.  You then cut and polish them to reveal the beautiful minerals underneath.

Hemingway's writing uses few words and simple sentences.  By "cutting away" the extra words, you can "see through" the sentence and understand the meaning more clearly.  Just like how you cut through a stone in lapidary to see the beauty within.

Comment: this is a much better answer than mine, good research

Answer (score 1):

I am going to come right out and admit I had to Google Lapidary, apparently it refers to the engraving, cutting and polishing of precious stones.

I reckon this is referring to something which starts out unrefined but with great potential,  which through hard work and skill is transformed into something exquisite.